# What is the shortest path to explore some points

Tags: algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence

There are N points in the graph, every point have a path to the other (N-1) points with a cost(ex. the cost is the line distance or the manhattan distance).

For any points A, B, C, there is two constrains:

cost(A->B) <= cost(A->C) + cost(C->B)

cost(A->B) == cost(B->A)

Now, what I want to do is to find the shortest paths to explore all the points in the graph. What is the method? Or there isn't a propel method for this problem.

I have an idea, assume that A is the start point, we try to find the nearest point from A(assume it is B), then I move to the point B. And I try to find the nearest point from B(A is removed now) again, till I explore all the points.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [Dijkstra's algorithm.](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

Summarizing the link:

```
Start at an arbitrary source node. 
Set the distance between this node and all other nodes = +Infinity
Set the distance between this node and itself to, well, 0 :)
Iterate:
    Mark this node as 'visited'
    Find the distance between this node and its directly connected neighbors
    Update their distances if smaller 
    Go to the next unvisited neighbor which has the smallest distance from the source
     If no neighbors are unvisited, go back a step until you can find an unvisited neighbor. 
     If all neighbors of all nodes are visited, terminate.
```

Now you have a fully populated table of the distances from the source to every node. Select the minimum to find the optimal path. Note also that following this algorithm with a fully connected graph will also give you the minimal spanning tree, I believe, since it will always choose the smallest distance between two nodes, without repeating any.

Comment: The answer is correct. +1. But, you need to expand this answer with more details, and mention Bellman Ford too.

Comment: But I provide a direct path for any two points in the graph. I think the conditions are more relaxed.

Comment: I actually didn't know about [Bellman-Ford](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman–Ford_algorithm) until you mentioned it, thanks.  My mind went straight to Dijkstra's based on seeing the words shortest path.